# Debug android widget using Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-widget

I create a android widget using Android Studio, but I have a problem debug my widget. I try with these steps:

1. Run my widget and I can see it in widgets and I can put it on Home Screen;
2. I open DDMS and I can see widget process, but I can not press the green debug button. Here is an image:
   [image]

Does anyone has idea why?

Comment: don't debug your widget on a real (physical) device , use emulators like bluestacks,it will work

Comment: emulators run very slow or they don't start using Android Studio

Comment: I succeed with emulator:)

Comment: happy for that :))